# Cordova emulate ios: Invalid device state

Tags: cordova, intellij-idea, ios-simulator

When I try to emulate a phonegap/cordova project with `sudo phonegap run ios --verbose` I get the console log:

```
An error was encountered processing the command (code=146):
Invalid device state

ENOENT, no such file or directory '/Users/<user>/Library/Logs/CoreSimulator/61A2A261-C1D4-4E31-B5DA-4C97191F1656/system.log'

Error code 1 for command: ios-sim with args: launch,/Users/<user>/.../mobile/platforms/ios/build/emulator/Hello World.app,--devicetypeid,com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPhone-5,--stderr,/Users/<user>/.../mobile/platforms/ios/cordova/console.log,--stdout,/Users/<user>/.../mobile/platforms/ios/cordova/console.log,--exit

Command finished with error code 2: /Users/.../ios/cordova/run --target=iPhone-5

ERROR running one or more of the platforms: Error: /Users/<user>/.../mobile/platforms/ios/cordova/run: Command failed with exit code 2
You may not have the required environment or OS to run this project
```

and the app don't start.
I can access `ios-sim` (v4.1.1), `cordova` (v5.1.1) and `phonegap` (5.1.1-0.29.0) via console.

Another strange thing is that when I go into run configuration in Intellij, there is a warning: `Cannot detect ios-sim in path`. XCode and the Developer Tools are up-to-date. I'm using a Mac OS X Yosemite. Can someone help me?

Comment: It is likely a permissions problem because you are using sudo with your phonegap commands. Check this out: http://zacvineyard.com/blog/2015/11/ionic-invalid-device-state-error-with-xcode-7-solved

Answer (score 6):

You can try

```
npm install -g ios-sim
npm install -g ios-deploy
```